# ANT script. Replacing dynamic values from one file with values from another

Tags: xml, dynamic, ant

I need some help with replacing dynamic values. I am new to ant scripting and require some assistance.

I currently have one file on a server which will hold the properties that are specific for that server. i.e database connection details

```
ydkprefs.dbClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
ydkprefs.dbType=DB2
ydkprefs.dbURL=jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/application
ydkprefs.dbschema=SCHEMA
ydkprefs.dbUsername=db2inst1
```

and then I have a template xml file with dynamic properties i.e.

```
 <Database Name=${dbName} className="${dbClassName}"
                dbType="${dbType}" folder=""
                jdbcURL="${dbURL}"
                schema="${dbschema}" user="${dbUsername}"/>
```

I have looked through a number of sites and I am none the wiser. The most promising information. The only thing that I have found that can work is to replace individual values which are stated within the ant script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could change the property file and/or the template to make it so that the property names in the property file *exactly* match the placeholders you want to replace in the target file, then you could do it with

```
<copy file="template.xml" tofile="target.xml" encoding="UTF-8">
  <filterset begintoken="$${" endtoken="}" filtersfile="db.properties" />
</copy>
```

In order to produce well formed XML output you would also need to ensure that the property *values* are properly XML escaped where necessary, e.g. if you need to use an `&` character in a value then it needs to be `&amp;` in the properties file.

Comment: I tip my hat to you sir. Thank you very much.